# Spaces at the start of every other line in a for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm attempting to get spaces at the beginning of every other line of the output of this program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Checkerboard
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int num;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println ("What is the integer?");
        num = input.nextInt();

        for (int x = 0; x < num; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < num; y++)
            {
                System.out.print("A ");
             }
         System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this program, if the user enters "4" for example, is:

```
A A A A A
A A A A A
A A A A A
A A A A A
```

I'm trying to get it to look like this:

```
A A A A A
 A A A A A
A A A A A
 A A A A A
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Print the extra space only for even values of x

```
for (int x = 0; x < num; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < num; y++)
    {
         System.out.print("A ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
    if (x % 2 == 0){
         System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

To be more explicit, the `%` operator (modulus) will return the *remainder* of a division operation.  So any even number modulu 2 will return 0.  Otherwise it would return 1.  13 % 10 == 3 because 13 / 10 = 1 remainder of 3.

Comment: Tried this but it still gave me a different output.  Was the same except it combined the 2nd and 3rd line of A's into the same line.

Comment: @PatrickR. sorry, you're right.  I edited my answer for clarity, and replaced a println with a normal print.